# List all parameterized test before running

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, junit5

When my project ran unit tests with JUnit4, my parameterized tests would list all the tests that were going to be run before actually starting to run the parameterized tests. Now, after switching to JUnit5, when I run parameterized tests, the name of the tests only become visible in the editor once they have run. This occurs in both Intellij and Eclipse.

Is there any way, with JUnit5, to have the all the parameterized test names listed before starting the run?

Thanks.

-------------- EDIT FOR CLARITY --------

Here is an example of two parameterized tests.

First JUnit4:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class) public class ParameterizedJUnit4 {

    public final static int STRING_SIZE = 10;

    static String getAlphaNumericString(int n) {
        byte[] array = new byte[256];
        new Random().nextBytes(array);
        String randomString = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer();
        String AlphaNumericString = randomString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");

        for (int k = 0; k < AlphaNumericString.length(); k++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(AlphaNumericString.charAt(k)) && (n > 0)
                    || Character.isDigit(AlphaNumericString.charAt(k)) && (n > 0)) {
                r.append(AlphaNumericString.charAt(k));
                n--;
            }
        }
        return r.toString();
    }

    @Parameters(name = "{index}: id {0}")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        Random r = new Random();
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = r.nextInt(250);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            names.add(getAlphaNumericString(STRING_SIZE));
        }
        List<Object[]> objects = new ArrayList();
        for (String id : names) {
            objects.add(new Object[]{id, r.nextInt(500)});
        }
        return objects;
    }

    private String testName;
    private int testValue;

    public ParameterizedJUnit4(String name, int value) {
        this.testName = name;
        this.testValue = value;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        Assert.assertEquals(200, testValue);
    }
}
```

When run in IntelliJ (or Eclipse), I see the total list of all names tests cases displayed before the tests are run. Then, as each test case is executed, it is marked as passed or failed. See below screenshot from IntelliJ:

[image]

However, when I execute the same test using JUnit5:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ParameterizedJUnit5 {

    public final static int STRING_SIZE = 10;

    static String getAlphaNumericString(int n) {
        byte[] array = new byte[256];
        new Random().nextBytes(array);
        String randomString = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer();
        String AlphaNumericString = randomString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");

        for (int k = 0; k < AlphaNumericString.length(); k++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(AlphaNumericString.charAt(k)) && (n > 0)
                    || Character.isDigit(AlphaNumericString.charAt(k)) && (n > 0)) {
                r.append(AlphaNumericString.charAt(k));
                n--;
            }
        }
        return r.toString();
    }

    static List<Arguments> data() {
        Random r = new Random();
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = r.nextInt(250);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            names.add(getAlphaNumericString(STRING_SIZE));
        }
        List<Arguments> objects = new ArrayList();
        for (String id : names) {
            objects.add(Arguments.of(id, r.nextInt(500)));
        }
        return objects;
    }

    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index}: id {0}")
    @MethodSource("data")
    public void test(String testName, int testValue) throws InterruptedException {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        Assertions.assertEquals(200, testValue);
    }
}
```

The list of tests is not displayed before running. Instead each test only appears in the execution window as it is run, and not before. See below screenshot from IntelliJ:

[image]

Our library needs some of the feature in JUnit5, but users are requesting that this feature for displaying lists of parameterized tests before running is not lost. Is there any way to get this functionality in JUnit5?

Thanks,
-Mark

Comment: Please provide a sample project where you experience the different behaviour with Junit 4 and Junit 5 Parameterized tests. Thanks

Comment: I have updated accordingly OlgaKlisho.

Comment: This becomes a very big deal when you have a lot of tests that take a very long time to run

Comment: Thanks for providing the detailed sample. Seems that implementation works like this for Junit5. You may use parallel mode, i.e defining "junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true" and 
"junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent" in junit-platform.properties file so that groups of tests are listed out in Test runner pane, but unfortunately still not all the tests will be listed at once.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Is there any way to request this as a feature in future? We run a lot of very large parameterized tests, and the ability to stop and run an individual test before executing the entire set would be quite benefitial.

Comment: I do not think that JUnit 5 is usable at this time because of this. @OlgaKlisho